Quartz .NET wtih ADOJobStore how to check if job is created?
I have a Quartz.NET application with ADOJobStore
We create our jobs(Cron jobs that execute once a day) on a application start within AddQuartz using AddJob/AddTrigger
It seems like on each restart jobs are updated in DB (as expected) and it looks like because of this our misfire policy doesn't work.
We have configured misfire with WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed, I started app, then closed it, started it again only after NEXT_FIRE_TIME in DB + 1 minute, but job wasn't triggered.
Basically my question is - if there's a way to know that job is already created during AddQuartz?
